# Do not disturb mode doesn't work after upgrading to Android 12

Tags: do-not-disturb

I've got a OnePlus Nord CE 5G. "**Do not disturb**" mode was working fine with **Android 11**.
Since the upgrade to **Android 12**, it stopped working properly. It shows as activated but I keep getting **some** notifications and sounds (not all of them, but no clue which ones they do and which ones they don't). The settings are correctly configured to **not** get any notification from any application, and still, I keep getting some even with the screen lock.

Any idea of what to do or how to go back to Android 11?

Comment: I had same problem with Android 13.
Eventually, I downgraded to Android 11 and now It's working again.